# KivyMD why app on pc looks different on mobile

Tags: android, kivy, kivymd

Here is the pitures of PC app and Mobile app:
PC - https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Bkvp.jpg
Mobile - https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFYbW.jpg
what i need to do to make this work? do i need to run the mobile app everytime to make changes?

kv file here (im not sure how to indent):

```
FloatLayout:
canvas:
    Color:
        rgba: 66/255, 66/255, 66/255, 1
    RoundedRectangle:
        pos: (5, 5)
        size: self.width -10, self.height -10
        radius: [50]


MDLabel:
    text: 'Amount'
    bold: True
    theme_text_color: 'Custom'
    text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    halign: 'center'
    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.15, 'center_y':0.6}

MDTextFieldRound:
    id: amount_text
    text: '0'
    size_hint: 0.15,0.05
    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.20, 'center_y':0.53}
    line_color: 76/255, 182/255, 172/255, 1
    foreground_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    normal_color: 76/255, 182/255, 172/255, 1


MDLabel:
    text: 'From'
    bold: True
    theme_text_color: 'Custom'
    text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    halign: 'center'
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.38, 'center_y':0.6}

MDFillRoundFlatButton:
    id: menu_button1
    text: 'USD'
    font_size: 20
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.45, 'center_y': 0.53}
    size_hint: 0.23, 0.05
    md_bg_color: 76/255, 182/255, 172/255, 1
    on_press: app.menu1.open()


MDLabel:
    text: 'To'
    bold: True
    theme_text_color: 'Custom'
    text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    halign: 'center'
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.72, 'center_y':0.6}

MDFillRoundFlatButton:
    id: menu_button2
    text: 'ILS'
    font_size: 20
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.8, 'center_y': 0.53}
    size_hint: 0.23, 0.05
    md_bg_color: 76/255, 182/255, 172/255, 1
    on_press: app.menu2.open()


MDRaisedButton:
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.62, 'center_y': 0.53}
    size_hint: (None, None)
    width: dp(2100)
    md_bg_color: 66/255, 66/255, 66/255, 1
    on_press: app.change()

    Image:
        source: 'convert.png'


MDFillRoundFlatButton:
    text: 'Convert'
    pos_hint: {'x':0.8, 'center_y':0.4}
    md_bg_color: 100/255, 170/255, 210/255, 1
    on_press: app.convert()


MDTextField:
    text: '0'
    id: result
    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.3}
    size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
    font_size: 32
    halign: 'center'
    line_color_normal: 76/255, 182/255, 172/255, 1
    readonly: True
```

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you have pixel measurements, make sure you use measurement units instead. For example, instead of `font_size: 32`, write `font_size: dp(32)` or `font_size: '32dp'` in your kv file. This will make sure sizes remain constant across different screen densities. See [Kivy Metrics](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.metrics.html) for more.

If you want the buttons and text field to look the exact same, you would need to manually create your own widget subclass and take a look at the KivyMD source as there's no easy way to configure the radius of these widgets.

Comment: nice, how i do this with the buttons? i tried to do this with pos/size hint but it did not work well on mobile. i can only do this with normal pos/size?

Comment: Yes. Size hint and position hint use the dimensions of the screen, so they are not pixel measurements. Initially I thought there was a way to change the button radiuses to match the textfield but this is not the case. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

The design differs from one operating system to another in some libraries such as kivymd and some are fixed such as kivy

Comment: oh so there is no such a problem with kivy? there is a better way to do this than making changes and run with buildozer everytime?

Comment: I don't know about that